# Get Tracking number using API in UPS Shipping method

Tags: php, ups

Can anybody tell me is it possible to get tracking number using UPS API ? If yes How ?

In my current system admin has to add tracking number manually.

Comment: Have you done anything to research it, tried any code or looked through the API functions? The [API itself](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit) seems quite well documented?

Comment: yes, i tried a lots . evrywhere i get api to find tracking information of shipping by using tracking number. but not find how to get tracking number online using API

Comment: Do you want to expand your question perhaps with what information you have, want to try to provide to the API to get the tracking number of the item you want to find?

Comment: i don't have more information related to get tracking number. But i have API which send me current shipping status of my order using tracking number. Now i have a question is that  ups gives any API that give track number into response. At present i have to add tracking number manually. .....

Comment: If anybody can tell you the answer it's UPS, it's their service afterall. Have you contacted them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get a tracking number from UPS is creating a shipment using the Shipping API. Currently, UPS **does not** have a service in which you request shipments (or tracking numbers) for a period of time belonging to a given account.

Best!